# Lambda function triggered on loop for unknown reason

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have a lambda function that is triggered by S3 Put events (the only trigger for this function).

Recently this lambda was triggered 650k times in two days.

When looking into S3 events, the S3 Put event was triggered less than 1k times.

At first we assumed that the function was running on a loop due to errors or timeouts, but the function had only a single error in that timeframe, due to a timeout.

Does anybody know what may have triggered our Lambda Function?

Thanks!

Comment: There could be many events trigger your function. SQS, SNS, CloudWatch Events, DynamoDB, external triggers...

Comment: What does to this lambda does ? Does its processing triggers other lambda, Or service which in turn triggers back this lambda. In simple words is there any other trigger defined for this lambda...which is causing this. To remediate this I will suggest enable detailed cloudtrail in your account and observe those as and when this happens again.

Comment: There are no other registered triggers besides the S3 bucket.
The function sends a message to a SNS topic with the path which triggered the lambda, in order to broadcast the change in S3. We don't send the event straight to SNS because we need it to be a FIFO topic, which is not currently supported by S3 event notification